# Google sheets calculation for a period of time, please assist

Tags: google-sheets

Use sumifs to calculate "the profit" on "monday" between 0:00 and 1:00.
C:C profit, A:A date and B:B time. The function below does not return anything

=SUMIFS(C1:C1000,A1:A1000,"Monday",B1:B1000,">=00:00",B1:B1000,"<01:00")

Can someone assist me by using google sheets calculation the output being profits made between different times and for days of the week? Below is the sample data

Below is the blank sheet maker
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6CcaUyry48kogVNmyogFytjGiRWwXIKO7_ikwLik4k/edit

Comment: No question here then, looks like you have it solved.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `filter()`, like this:

```
=sum( 
  filter( 
    A2:A, 
    text(B2:B, "ddd") = "Mon", 
    value("0:00 am") <= C2:C, C2:C < value("1:00 pm") 
  ) 
)
```

The formula above assumes that profits are in column `A2:A`, dates in column `B2:B` and times in column `C2:C` as per the *table* shown in the question. In the event those values are in a different order in the columns suggested by the *formula* in the question, use this instead:

```
=sum( 
  filter( 
    C1:C, 
    text(A1:A, "ddd") = "Mon", 
    value("0:00 am") < B1:B, B1:B < value("1:00 pm") 
  ) 
)
```

You can also use [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175), like this:

```
=sum( 
  filter( 
    Profit, 
    text(Date, "ddd") = "Mon", 
    value("0:00 am") <= Time, Time < value("1:00 pm") 
  ) 
)
```

The three named ranges must be exactly of the same height.

If the spreadsheet locale is such that the name of Monday is something else, replace `Mon` with something else. You should also use 24-hour time format such as `13:00` instead of `01:00 pm` when the locale so requires.

The layout of data in your sample spreadsheet differs considerably from what you present in the question. Further, the values in column `P` are not dates but text strings that just look like dates.

With those handicaps, you can best get an hourly report pivoted by day of week using a couple of helper columns and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    daySerial, 
    if( 
      len(daySerial), 
      weekday(daySerial, 2) & text(daySerial, " dddd"), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    )
  )( 
    iferror(value(substitute(P2:P, ".", "/"))) 
  ) 
)
```

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(Q2:Q), 
    value(regexextract(to_text(Q2:Q), "\d+")), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

```
=query( 
  N1:U, 
  "select U, sum(N) 
   where U is not null 
   group by U 
   pivot T", 
  1 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6CcaUyry48kogVNmyogFytjGiRWwXIKO7_ikwLik4k/edit#gid=1257202584).

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it does not seem to work. The error message  is 'no matches are found in filter evaluation'

Comment: I have updated the question and added a sample spreadsheet. if you have time, can you kindly look at the question. Thanks

Comment: My country is not present in the Locale. By default it on USA. I even changed the time formatting.

Comment: I used this formula to get the profit between two intervals and it works. =SUMIFS(Profit, Time,">=0:00",Time,"<=1:00"). When I try to get profit between two intervals on a weekday it faints.

Comment: I do use named ranges. How do I upload the blank sheet maker?

Comment: Edited the answer per the layout of your sample spreadsheet.